# How to return metric of label A only if during specified time same metric with label B was not recorded?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a counter metric `my_event` which has label `mode = A | B`, label `pod` (POD is a k8s pod id) and some other labels. What I need is to to display graph showing `my_event / per second` per each `pod`. However I want to take into account only events with label `mode = A` AND only if events with label `mode = B` was not recorded during the given time (for same pod). If during given time event with label `mode = B` was recorded at least one time then graph value should be null for this time. By "given time" I mean "lookback" vector like `[5m]`.

So when prom is checking every "point" for last [5m] for one pod then:

- if there were 300 events with label `mode = A` and 0 events with label `mode = B` then it should report 300/50m = 1 event per sec
- if there were 300 events with label `mode = A` and 1+ events with label `mode = B` then it should report null (no data)

All this should be grouped by label `pod` (show data per each pod).

For now my query looks like this (it displays events with label `mode = A` per second for each pod:

```
sum (rate(event_proc_worker_events_total{mode="A"}[5m])) by (pod)
```

How I can modify this query to return null if during [5m] event with `mode = B` occured on same pod?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using logical operators, specifically "unless". To quote documentation:

> **vector1 unless vector2** results in a vector consisting of the elements of vector1 for which there are no elements in vector2 with exactly matching label sets. All matching elements in both vectors are dropped.

Something like this should work:

```
sum(                                                
  rate(event_proc_worker_events_total{mode="A"}[5m])
) by (pod)
unless 
(      
  sum( 
    rate(event_proc_worker_events_total{mode="B"}[5m])
  ) by (pod)
  > 0
)
```